# Messages app not responding / hang in M1 MacBook Air

Tags: messages, apple-silicon

I tried to delete some messages from the Messages application from my M1 MacBook Air.

It was working at first then suddenly stop working and keep loading. I tried to Force Quit, restart my Mac, and Safe Mode boot up. Nothing worked. Every time I opened it, it stops responding as soon as it started.

Please help.

Below are some details from the report after I Force Quit the app.

```
Date/Time:        2022-06-01 22:18:31.094 +0630
End time:         2022-06-01 22:18:32.698 +0630
OS Version:       macOS 12.4 (Build 21F79)
Architecture:     arm64e
Report Version:   35.1
Incident Identifier: B58D9B0D-8CE5-49E9-BE78-E9867F983C5B
Share With Devs:  Yes

Data Source:      Stackshots
Shared Cache:     513553BB-5CA5-3B9E-A613-B0603FFE3038 slid base address 0x1927b8000, slide 0x127b8000
Shared Cache:     2C613240-2C81-3842-88AE-7A8CF7EAE215 slid base address 0x1d32a0000, slide 0x532a0000
Shared Cache:     53B6853F-0BC3-33F5-BE72-1ACA3A188FF8 slid base address 0x7ff802a90000, slide 0x2a90000

Command:          Messages
Path:             /System/Applications/Messages.app/Contents/MacOS/Messages
Identifier:       com.apple.MobileSMS
Version:          14.0 (6000)
Build Version:    11
Project Name:     Messages_iosmac
Source Version:   1174100051000000
Architecture:     arm64e
PID:              9850
Time Since Fork:  7s

Event:            hang
Duration:         1.60s
Steps:            17 (100ms sampling interval)

Hardware model:   MacBookAir10,1
Active cpus:      8
HW page size:     16384
VM page size:     16384

Time Awake Since Boot: 47887s
Time Since Wake:  13331s

Total CPU Time:   5.253s (12.7G cycles, 34.1G instructions, 0.37c/i)
Advisory levels:  Battery -> 3, User -> 2, ThermalPressure -> 0, Combined -> 2
Free disk space:  86.76 GB/228.27 GB, low space threshold 3072 MB
```

Comment: Try deleting the ***contents*** of `~/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.iChat.savedState` [don't delete the folder, it's an alias]

Comment: Thank you so much. Your comment give me the right direction. I deleted content inside ~/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.MobileSMS.savedState  and it works fine again.